# python example of a motor hardware interface

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a 4WD robot that uses PWM motor controls. I am looking for a good ROS2 **python** example to convert Twist signal in PWM.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401644/python-example-of-a-motor-hardware-interface/) by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2022-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-31**:
What model of controllers do you have for these PWM motors? This [package `simple_drive`](http://wiki.ros.org/simple_drive) and this AutomaticAddison [blog post](https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-control-a-robots-velocity-remotely-using-ros/) describe similar things you can try to achieve here

**Comment by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) on 2022-06-05**:
thanks, I've written very similar code. I was looking for something which included odom for a bot without encoders.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-06-06**:
How would it work exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To convert Twist message to PWM that's what I've done

1. I've created a test script that sends PWM duty cycle signal from the lowest to highest at specific time intervals (e.g. 1sec, 2sec and son on).
2. For each event (e.g. PWM 50 for 2sec) I've measured the distance covered by the robot.
3. With distances (x) and duty cycles (y) I've calculated the slope(m) and y-intercept(b) values of a linear equation y = mx + b
4. With the linear function I can calculate the duty cycle needed. So, for instance from the Twist linear.x velocity message value, defined as meters/second, I can derive the duty cycle. Note that when the robot goes from a stop state to a moving state some initial friction needs to be considered.

Example

```
def calc_vel(self, x, z): # x and z are coming from Twist 
    t = self.track #distance between wheels
    
    r_vel = x + ((z * t) /2)
    l_vel = x - ((z * t) /2)
    
    dc_r = calc_duty_cycle(r_vel)
    dc_l = calc_duty_cycle(dc_l)
    
    return dc_r, dc_l

def calc_duty_cycle(self, vel):
    # linear equation variables defined by experimentation
    M_SLOPE = 50
    Y_INTERCEPT = 2
    
    return M_SLOPE * vel + Y_INTERCEPT
```

---

Originally posted by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) with karma: 33 on 2022-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1